# Particles not showing up

Tags: particles

I'm in the cycles render and my particles aren't showing. Its so weird because i did the exact same thing to another project and it showed up there. [image]

Comment: Circle doesnt have faces

Comment: How can circle emit particles from faces , you must first extrude the circles vertex and then fill them

Comment: I did! The circles are extruded. Its weird because I did the same exact thing on another project and that worked. Its like a hit or miss